# List all gradle tasks which trigger this task

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

There are multiple questions related to viewing gradle task dependencies, that is, given Task X, what other tasks will be triggered.

Is there a plugin to perform the opposite calculation, that is, given Task X, list all of the tasks which would cause Task X to be executed.